# How to make brackets bigger?

Tags: braces

I have the following expression here.

```
$$\{\|\frac{f_i(x_i+h)-f_i(x-k)}{h}\|\}$$
```

I want to make the outer most brackets and the modulus sign to be bigger.

I have tried

```
$$\Bigg{\Bigg|\frac{f_i(x_i+h)-f_i(x-k)}{h}\Bigg|\Bigg}$$
```

but this doe not seem to work.

What can I do?

Comment: `\Biggl\{\biggl|...\biggr|\Biggr\}`.  And **don’t use `$$`!**

Comment: They work fine, but the braces are `\{ ... \}` not `{...}`, also consider using `\Biggl ... \Biggr` in order to get the correct classes.

Comment: Please see [Why is `\[ ... \]` preferable to `$$ ... $$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/69818)

Answer (score 2):

`\Bigg{` and `\Bigg}` are errors; it should be `\Bigg\{` and `\Bigg\}`, respectively.

Actually, there's no need to `\Bigg` (pun intended) -- `\bigg` is the correct size for the fractional term at hand. Thus, you should enter the displayed equation as follows:

```
\[
\biggl\{\biggl| \frac{f_i(x_i+h)-f_i(x-k)}{h} \biggr|\biggr\}
\]
```

Note that I use `\biggl` and `\biggr` instead of just `\bigg` for the "fence symbols". For the present equation this makes no difference in appearance. However, there would be a major difference if the fractional expression were preceded by a unary minus (or plus) symbol.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `\right\{` and `\left\{`. These commands adjust the size of the braces to their contents.

Comment: `\{`. Your answer has the same omission as the OP.